# How to return a constant string?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have recently started learning solidity. I added a function `showMessage()` like below:

```
function showMessage() public view returns(string memory) {
        return "This is a constant";
    }
```

In the truffle console when I call it `helloworld.showMessage()` it gives error:

```
truffle(ganache)> helloworld.showMessage()
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
helloworld.showMessage()
           ^

Uncaught TypeError: helloworld.showMessage is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:12
    at sigintHandlersWrap (node:vm:273:12)
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:140:14)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:270:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:285:1)
    at bound (node:domain:416:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:427:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:834:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:470:12)
```

The method is right there as you can see here the output which is generated if I print `helloworld` variable:

```
 },
    events: { allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
    _address: '0xEb1799BA2295143d0A85FF6939c53fEC3ED42eaC',
    _jsonInterface: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  getMessage: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  setMessage: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  showMessage: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
  send: [Function (anonymous)],
  allEvents: [Function (anonymous)],
  getPastEvents: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Below is my entire contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract HelloWorld {
    string private message = "hello world";

    function getMessage() public view returns(string memory) {
        return message;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }

    function showMessage() public view returns(string memory) {
        return "This is a constant";
    }
}
```

The rest of the functions work fine.

**Update**:

NO I was wrong. After updating the contract and rebuilding and migrate, it is saying every function *undefined* after compiling and deployment. In Truffle console I initiated as:

```
let helloworld = HelloWorld.deployed(
helloworld.setMessage('mssg')
```

It worked first time.